# Bash adding unknown extra characters to command in script

Tags: bash

I am currently trying to create a script that executes a program 100 times, with different parameters, typically pretty simple, but it's adding strange characters into the output filename that is passed into the command call for the program, the script i have written goes as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100}
do ./generaterandomizedlist 10 input/input_10_$i.txt
done
```

I've taken a small screenshot of the output file name here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRjIf.jpg

(extra characters are not recognized by chrome so simply pasting the name doesn't work)

It doesn't do this when i manually call the command issued in the script, any ideas?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info; the answer to many `bash`-related questions can be found there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has some stray CRs in it. Use `dos2unix` or `tr` to fix it.